# Sorting all values from "keys" and "values"

Tags: python

essentially I am trying to do this:
Return a "last name to first name(s)" dictionary with the people
    from the "person to friends" dictionary person_to_friends.
And I am not able to get the names from repeating

```
>>>def get_last_to_first(
...person_to_friends: Dict[str, List[str]]) -> Dict[str, List[str]]
... get_last_to_first(P2F) == {
...    'Katsopolis': ['Jesse'],
...    'Tanner': ['Danny R', 'Michelle', 'Stephanie J'],
...    'Gladstone': ['Joey'],
...    'Donaldson-Katsopolis': ['Rebecca'],
...    'Gibbler': ['Kimmy'],
...    'Tanner-Fuller': ['DJ']}
True
P2F =      {'Jesse Katsopolis': ['Danny R Tanner', 'Joey Gladstone',
            'Rebecca Donaldson-Katsopolis'],
            'Rebecca Donaldson-Katsopolis': ['Kimmy Gibbler'],
            'Stephanie J Tanner': ['Michelle Tanner', 'Kimmy Gibbler'],
            'Danny R Tanner': ['Jesse Katsopolis', 'DJ Tanner-Fuller',
            'Joey Gladstone']}
"""
person = {}
person1 = {}
for key in person_to_friends.keys():
    num = key.rfind(' ')
    person[key[num:]] = [key[:num]]
for val in person_to_friends.values():
    for item in val:
        numf = item.rfind(' ')
        if item[numf:] not in person:
            person[item[numf:]] = [item[:numf]]
        else:
            person[item[numf:]].append(item[:numf])
print(person)
```

Comment: Your output contains different elements to your input, so this problem is not just about sorting - please edit the question to describe specifically what you are trying to do.

Comment: is this Better?

Comment: Thank goodness someone understands what you are asking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `set` instead of `list` will fix it automatically for you:

```
def get_last_to_first(
        person_to_friends: Dict[str, List[str]]) -> Dict[str, List[str]]:
    """Return a "last name to first name(s)" dictionary with the people
    from the "person to friends" dictionary person_to_friends.

    >>> get_last_to_first(P2F) == {
    ...    'Katsopolis': ['Jesse'],
    ...    'Tanner': ['Danny R', 'Michelle', 'Stephanie J'],
    ...    'Gladstone': ['Joey'],
    ...    'Donaldson-Katsopolis': ['Rebecca'],
    ...    'Gibbler': ['Kimmy'],
    ...    'Tanner-Fuller': ['DJ']}
    True
    P2F =      {'Jesse Katsopolis': ['Danny R Tanner', 'Joey Gladstone',
                'Rebecca Donaldson-Katsopolis'],
                'Rebecca Donaldson-Katsopolis': ['Kimmy Gibbler'],
                'Stephanie J Tanner': ['Michelle Tanner', 'Kimmy Gibbler'],
                'Danny R Tanner': ['Jesse Katsopolis', 'DJ Tanner-Fuller',
                'Joey Gladstone']}
    """
    person = {}
    person1 = {}
    for key in person_to_friends.keys():
        num = key.rfind(' ')
        # person[key[num:]] = set([key[:num]])
        if key[num:] not in person:
            person[key[num:]] = set([key[:num]])
        else:
            person[key[num:]].add(key[:num])

    for val in person_to_friends.values():
        for item in val:
            numf = item.rfind(' ')
            if item[numf:] not in person:
                person[item[numf:]] = set([item[:numf]])
            else:
                person[item[numf:]].add(item[:numf])
    print(person)
```

**Edit**
The reason it was not containing `Stephanie J Tanner` is because you were overwriting the key for the first level, changed on the code above.

---

You could benefit of pythons list/dict comprehension and defaultdict to make it easiar.

```
from collections import defaultdict
def simple(p2f):
    all_names = set(x for k, v in p2f.items() for x in [k] + v)
    person = defaultdict(set)
    for p in all_names:
        *first_name, last_name = p.split()
        person[last_name].add(" ".join(first_name))
    print(person)
    return person
```

Comment: I noticed its skipping over the name stephanie J Tanner, could you tell me why

Comment: how can I fix it, could you send me in the right direction

Comment: I've added to the code on my answer: `# person[key[num:]] = set([key[:num]])
        if key[num:] not in person:
            person[key[num:]] = set([key[:num]])
        else:
            person[key[num:]].add(key[:num])`